# How do I expand this javascript/html or correctly write it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am semi new to javascript. I have the basics of it.  (I came from using HAXE programming language to make simple 2d games).  I was trying to implement a drop down sort on a huge amount of data.  I failed horribly.  So I looked up a few example and found this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlCountry,#ddlAge").on("change", function () {
            var country = $('#ddlCountry').find("option:selected").val();
            var age = $('#ddlAge').find("option:selected").val();
            SearchData(country, age)
        });
    });
    function SearchData(country, age) {
        if (country.toUpperCase() == 'ALL' && age.toUpperCase() == 'ALL') {
            $('#table11 tbody tr').show();
        } else {
            $('#table11 tbody tr:has(td)').each(function () {
                var rowCountry = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
                var rowAge = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
                if (country.toUpperCase() != 'ALL' && age.toUpperCase() != 'ALL') {
                    if (rowCountry.toUpperCase() == country.toUpperCase() && rowAge == age) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                } else if ($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() != '') {
                    if (country != 'all') {
                        if (rowCountry.toUpperCase() == country.toUpperCase()) {
                            $(this).show();
                        } else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (age != 'all') {
                        if (rowAge == age) {
                            $(this).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
 
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<select class="cl_country" id="ddlCountry">
    <option value="all">Select Class </option>
    <option value="India">india</option>
    <option value="usa">usa</option>
    <option value="uk">uk</option>
</select>
<select class="cl_age" id="ddlAge">
    <option value="all">Select Class </option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
</select>
<table style="width: 100%" id="table11" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>country</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>INDIA</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sam</td>
        <td>AUSTRALIA</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>joe</td>
        <td>INDIA</td>
        <td>60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>alan</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>60</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tested it and its working exactly how what I was trying to do.

But I have 10+ additional Dropdowns to filter the huge amount of data.  I tried to expand this code by added new Vars, passing them into the searchData functions, etc.  Basically just adding new lines everywhere I found "age" and "country".  The data comes out looking correct, but the filtering does not work.

So I started to dig a little deeper into these nested if/else's.  The logic doesn't make sense to me.So it brings me to a few questions:

- What is the 'ALL' do/mean?
- To my understanding, the td:eq(#) grabs a position in the table?
- Why is everything converted to uppercase?
- How can I expand this code to include multiple selections.. Will it be a ton of if/else's or is this code written poorly and a simple loop will suffice?

Thanks! and I apologize if this is not worded as well as it could be.. all nighter and a broken coffee pot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the 'ALL' do/mean?

'ALL' comes from the following:

```
var country = $('#ddlCountry').find("option:selected").val();    
var age = $('#ddlAge').find("option:selected").val();
```

Which is then passed to your function SearchData (country, age)

> To my understanding, the td:eq(#) grabs a position in the table?

```
td:eq()
```

uses the eq selector which selects an element based on the index inside the parenthesis ().  Since there's no additional filters in place it will simply grab the td at that index.  Note: the index is 0-based so if there's 5 cells you would get cells 0,1,2,3,4.

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

> Why is everything converted to uppercase?

In this instance there's really no reason to convert to upper case (or lower case).  Typically it's to "normalize" input data from the user.  If they decided to type All, all, ALL, etc. converting them to "ALL" is easier to compare against.

> How can I expand this code to include multiple selections.. Will it be
> a ton of if/else's or is this code written poorly and a simple loop
> will suffice?

I can't answer much to this one without additional clarification of what you're trying to accomplish.  Right now it looks roughly like this for your logic:

```
If Country = "All" & Age = "All"
    Return Everything
If Country != '' Then
    If Country != 'All'
        Return Country rows that match
    If Age != 'All'
        Return Age rows that match
```

This code is redundant.  It compares if rowCountry != '' OR rowCountry != ''.  You could just replace $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() with rowCountry to make it easier to read.

```
$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() != '' || $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() != ''
```

You can see this rowCountry is set to the same value:

```
var rowCountry = $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
```

Comment: I really don't see any reason to include more than a single if/else statement to show/hide the row.  Even if you expand the logic.

Comment: Woops, meant to put this: To keep it (relatively) simple I'd probably wrap all of your filters in a comparison something like this : if((rowCountry == "All" || rowCountry == country) && (rowAge == 'All' || rowAge == age))